# Issue in inserting value with rhandsontable

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity, rhandsontable

Thanks for taking your valuable time to pitch in into this question. :-)

I'm building a shiny app that would take user inputs through **rhandsontable** and save it as a **.rds** file for data persistence.

The code is as follows:

**Global.r**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinycssloaders
library(rhandsontable)
library(htmltools)
library(plotly)
library(shinyjs)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

# Reads the data stored already
raw_data_projects <- readRDS("Projects.rds")

# code to refresh app so as to display the newly added data
jsResetCode <- "shinyjs.reset = function() {history.go(0)}"
```

**ui.R**

```
dashboardPage(skin = "black",
              dashboardHeader(dropdownMenuOutput("dropdownmenu"),title = "PMO Dashboard",
                              tags$li(div(img(src = 'TechM_logo.png',
                                                 height = "35px"),
                                                 style = "padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;"),
                                                 class = "dropdown"),dropdownMenuOutput("msgOutput")) ,
              dashboardSidebar(
                sidebarMenu(
                  menuItem("Home", tabName = "home", icon = icon("home")),
                  menuItem("Projects", tabName = "pros", icon = icon("briefcase")),
                  menuItem("About Team", tabName = "teamstr", icon = icon("user-friends")),
                  menuItem("Training & Skills",tabName = "skills",icon = icon("book"))
                )),
              dashboardBody(
                useShinyjs(),                  # Include shinyjs in the UI
                extendShinyjs(text = jsResetCode),
                tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "style_2.css"),
                tabItems(
                          tabItem(tabName = "pros",
                          fluidPage(tabBox(width = "500px",
                          tabPanel("Metrics",

                          fluidRow( 
                            valueBoxOutput("Completed", width = 3),
                            valueBoxOutput("WIP", width = 3),
                            valueBoxOutput("Delayed", width = 3),
                            valueBoxOutput("OnHold", width = 3)
                          ),

                          fluidRow(

                            box(plotlyOutput("Project_category"), width = 4,solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary", title = "Project Category", collapsible = TRUE),
                            box(plotlyOutput("Project_status"), width = 8,solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary", title = "Project Status", collapsible = TRUE),
                            box(plotlyOutput("Complexity"), width = 4,solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary", title = "Project Complexity", collapsible = TRUE),
                            box(plotlyOutput("Audits"), width = 4,solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary", title = "Audit Status", collapsible = TRUE)
                          )),
                          tabPanel("Data",

                                  box(withSpinner(rHandsontableOutput("Projects")), width = 12),
                                  actionButton("saveBtnProjects", "Save Projects", icon = icon("save")),
                                  actionButton("BtnResetProjects", "Reset Filters", icon = icon("eraser")))))
                  )))
```

**server.r**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
dt_projects <- reactive({ raw_data_projects })
  vals <- reactiveValues()

  output$Projects <- renderRHandsontable({

    rhandsontable(dt_projects(), readOnly = FALSE, search = TRUE, selectCallback = TRUE ) %>% 
      hot_cols(columnSorting = TRUE, manualColumnMove = TRUE, manualColumnResize = TRUE ) %>%
      hot_table(highlightRow = TRUE, highlightCol = TRUE) %>% 
      #hot_col("PROJECT.STATUS", renderer = text_renderer, type = "autocomplete") %>% 
      hot_rows(fixedRowsTop = 1)



  })

  # on click of button the file will be saved to the working directory
  observeEvent(input$saveBtnProjects, 
               #write.csv(hot_to_r(input$Projects), file = "./Data/project_tracker.csv",row.names = FALSE)
               saveRDS(hot_to_r(input$Projects),"Projects.rds")
  )

  # refresh the page
  observeEvent(input$saveBtnProjects, {js$reset()})

})
```

So when I run the app I get the table I desire as below:

[image: Screenshot of table]

As we can see, as I was inserting values to the first column, all the other columns greyed out and I couldn't insert any values into it. Please help me with this issue.

Also please suggest if my code will display the data reactively as soon as I save the data by pressing **Save Projects** button.

Thanks a ton in advance!!

P.S : I have included the server code only for the table considering the length of the question leaving the code of other tabs. But still this code is reproducible.

Comment: To improve the reproducibility of your example, I would suggest 1) remove the calls to load packages that are not necessary to run your example, and 2) do not include code that installs packages (it’s not a nice surprise to have some example code make permanent changes to your local system).

Comment: @CJYetman Hi CJ! I've edited the question to load only the required packages for code reproducibility. Could you please see what is the issue with the code. I've seen that even save and loading the **.rds** is not working fine. Thank you!

Comment: I’m not familiar with packages you are using here, so I can’t help with that. I ended up here because you were loading `networkD3`, which I am a maintainer of, but it is not actually relevant to your question.

Comment: Ok cool, thank you @CJYetman. At least could you vote this question so that someone could pick it up :-)

Comment: That’s not how the voting system is intended to work.